# Sync Exchange Calendar to Google Calendar

Tags: mac-osx, exchange, calendar

Without having access to the Exchange server, is there an app I can run on my OS X desktop to sync my Exchange-based calendar to Google Calendar?

I really don't mind if it just duplicates the events from Exchange to Google Cal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

a) The google sync is at Outlook level on desktop and not at Exchange Level. 
http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89960

b) Here's a guide on how to sync Exchange Calendar with iCal.
http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/outlook/item/748ea995-465e-4c40-88d2-7669c7f37a0d

c) There are various roll-your-own options using Exchange EWS Managed Api on MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx

hth

Comment: I need a solution for OSX...

Comment: You can try the ical option